# Twitter Error: Communication with the service provider failed: api.twitter.com

Tags: android, api, twitter, authentication, twitter-oauth

I am creating a twitter sharing by using [sugree's twitter-android-sdk](https://github.com/sugree/twitter-android-sdk). So when the activity starts i am calling..

```
Twitter tweet = new Twitter(R.drawable.icon);
     tweet.authorize(this, null, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", new TwitRequestListener());
```

I was working fine befor.  But suddenly i started getting this error:

04-25 12:03:28.346: DEBUG/twitter(458): Login failed: com.sugree.twitter.DialogError: Communication
with the service provider failed: api.twitter.com

Thanks in advance,
Aby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the twitter server.  It started working from next day.

Comment: I used the same library and it does not work, is yours still working or is it just temporary?