# Integrating Twitter to Android: Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:443

Tags: android, twitter, sdk

I am using the same SDK to integrate Twitter to my Android app as the following post:

[Sugree/twitter-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782103/twitter-error-communication-with-the-service-provider-failed-api-twitter-com)

And got the same error:

> D/twitter ( 2233): Login failed: com.sugree.twitter.DialogError: Communication with the service provider failed: Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:443

In above post, the OP said

> Problem was with the twitter server. It started working from next day.

But I tried many days, it is still not working, and opening the link: api.twitter.com in browser does work, so I wonder what the problem is, and, if there is any other WORKING library for twitter on Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of this I think you've not added the Internet permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file yet.

You should add the following line before your application can make requests:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

If this is not the case and it is the Java library, maybe you can try [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). This library is used in many Android applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did add it.

Comment: Can you post a little bit of your code and your manifest file? maybe we can find something that way.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like you are having problems connecting to the web - are you able to connect other apps on your emulator to the web? When I have problems with an internet connection through the emulator it shows up with no signal (e.g. there are no bars in the signal indicator and a little x by it). Have you been able to connect this app/other apps to the web on the emulator before?

Piro is right with Twitter4J - its a nice library that makes twitter integration on any java platform really easy. [there is a simple tutorial here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-twitter-reader.html), and a [more complex one covering the OAuth integration here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm sure the network is working, and the library I used is using Twitter4J.